# Assign single group ID based on 2 columns using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as per below structure

```
ID |A |B
A1 |33|
A2 |56|
A3 |56|33
A4 |66|
A5 |66|33
A6 |95|33
A7 |95|
A8 |95|
A9 |22|
A10|  |22
```

How can I group IDs based on values in A and B such that single ID is assigned to all rows which are interconnected by values in A and B?

Desired output

```
ID |A |B |Grp
A1 |33|  |1
A2 |56|  |1
A3 |56|33|1
A4 |66|  |1
A5 |66|33|1
A6 |95|33|1
A7 |95|  |1
A8 |95|  |1
A9 |22|  |2
A10|  |22|2
```

Comment: What do you mean by "are interconnected by values in A and B"? Is this a graph-theory question?

Comment: If you see above table, column ID - A1 to A8 have common values in A and B. e.g. A1 and A2 are connected because of A3, A4 is connected to A5 (value 66) which in turn is connected to A1 (value 33), so on. Hence, A1 to A8 should fall in 1 group. On other hand, A9 and A10 has no value which is there in A1 to A8. So it forms a separate group.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can't do this in a single step.   Here's a multi-step approach.   It's not meant to be performant, so hopefully this is a one-time operation.

Populate a temporary table using a cursor of all the distinct values in A & B. Inside the cursor, you query the original table to find any values that are paired with the value you are currently looking at.  When you find one, concatenate it with the current value in a separate string variable.  When you're done, the temporary table should look something like this:

```
Grp     Values
1       |33|56|66|95|
2       |22|
```

Then getting your desired output is a simple matter of doing a LIKE or CHARINDEX to match the A or B column in the original table to the Values in your temp table.